# Optimal YouTube embed dimensions

Tags: html, youtube, embed

Is there an optimal width or height when embedding a YouTube movie in a webpage? I.e. a width or height that creates the clearest picture without interpolation or fuzzyness in the image?

I'm looking for resolutions smaller than 640x480 in particular. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when you go to embed it it will give you optimal dimensions, but it really dosnt matter that much, the most important factor is the video quality!

Hope that helps! Littleswany!